# How to send divided audio file through socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send an audio (.ogg) from a client to one server. I'm encoding it with base64, then compressing it with zlib. For a couple of reasons, my goal is to send this audio in 'windows' with size of 340 bytes.

The side of the client seems to be working fine, but my server side is only receiving the first 340 bytes and stoping. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Client

```
import socket
import time
import datetime as dt
import base64

HOST = ''
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))

i = 0

for item in result:
    item = str(item)
    print(item)
    s.send(item.encode())
    i += 1
    print('i = ', i)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Server side

```
import sqlite3
import socket
import time
import datetime as dt
import base64
import zlib
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque


HOST = ''
PORT = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen()
audiofile = ''
i = 0

try:

    while True:

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        rect = str(dt.datetime.now())
        print('Conectado com', addr[0],':', str(addr[1]), ' recebido às ', rect)

        data1 = conn.recv(2048)

        data = data1.decode()

        print('data = ', data)

        audiofile = audiofile + data
        i += 1
        print('i = ', i)
        print('audiofile = ', audiofile)

        if not data:
            print('No Data Received!')


except:

    print('No data received...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn, addr = s.accept()` should be outside of the while loop.
Your code is waiting for a new connection after the first 340 bytes are received but you're client is sending the remaining of the file on the same connection.

Comment: damn, that's it! It may be useful accepting connection inside the loop only if I have multiple clients, right. I took the try/except out and left the accept outside the looping, and now it's working fine. Thank you, Aleesandro!